# FormattedString in RadSideDrawer

Tags: angular, nativescript, styling

I am working on an app using nativescript and angular. We have the RadSideDrawer in use, and I am currently trying to use FormattedString to highlight keywords in content, but the FormattedString content is never displayed inside the RadSideDrawer.

I found this issue with the RadSideDrawer, and they recommend using full syntax:

```
<Label>
    <Label.formattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <FormattedString.spans>
                <Span text="&#xf0d7;" fontFamily="FontAwesome" />
                <Span text="Test 1234" fontStyle="italic"  />
                <Span text="Test 5678" />
            </FormattedString.spans>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.formattedText>
</Label>
```

http://www.telerik.com/forums/text-of-formattedstring-within-page-not-visible-when-radsidedrawer-is-added-to-page

On the other hand, the documentation says that the full syntax does not work if i am using angular:

https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/formatted-string-ng#how-to-use-the-formattedstring-class-in-text

```
<Label>
    <FormattedString>
        <Span text="some content" fontWeight="Bold"></Span>
    </FormattedString>
</Label>
```

> This syntax differs from the FormattedString’s full syntax used in
>   NativeScript Core, shown below, **which does not work in Angular
>   apps**:

I also tried it, and yes it does not  seem to work in Angular apps. So, how can I convince Nativescript to display a FormattedString in RadSideDrawer while using angular?

Comment: formatted strings do work in angular, their documentation is wrong as i found out myself

Comment: Using the extended syntax too? Because the short syntax wont work in a RadSideDrawer - to be specific neither the short nor the long syntax worked for me.

Comment: no, the long syntax is for using in horrible xml files, angular uses standard html or nshtml for nativescript. so using the shorter syntax of a label tag, formattedstring tag and span tag will work